# node js buffer and var difference

Tags: node.js

while using node js if I use

```
buf1= new Buffer(50);
and var buf='';
```

what is the difference in this initialization.
when should we use buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are rather confused about this, or just worded this question in a strange manner. In my experience, it's pretty rare that you'll want to use a buffer over something like a string unless you are dealing with streaming or low-level operations. It seems like the first variable you declared is a buffer, and the second one is a string. If you add a little more context, I'd be able to help you decide whether you need a buffer or a string.

In general, I think the docs on Buffer are what you're after: http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer

Answer (score 0):

use buffer when you have to deal with binary data. e.g. for encoding
from utf8 to base64

```
const newString = new Buffer("string").toString('base64');
```

[For more details click here](https://betterprogramming.pub/an-introduction-to-buffer-in-node-js-2237a9bce9da)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).